# search for variable in multiple files within the same script

Tags: awk

i have a script which reads every line of a file and outputs based on certain match,

```
function tohyphen (o) {
    split (o,a,"to[-_]")
    split (a[2],b,"-")
    if (b[1] ~ / /) { k=""; p=""; }
    else { k=b[1]; p=b[2] }
    if (p ~ / /) { p="" }
    return k
}

print k, "is present in" , FILENAME
```

what i need to do is check if the value of k is present in say about 60 other files and print that filename and also it has to ignore the file which it was original reading, im currently doing this with grep , but the calling of grep so many times causes the cpu to go high, is there a way i can do this within the awk script itself.

Comment: Could you please post your grep command? It shouldn't be a big thing for the CPU if it's just 60 files.

Comment: grep "$k" *.cfg | grep "something1" | grep "something2" | cut -d -f2,3,4                                                                                the problem i think is that each file could have 10  to 20k lines so running grep for each of those line might be pushing the cpu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your pipeline `grep "$k" *.cfg | grep "something1" | grep "something2" | cut -d -f2,3,4` with the following single `awk` script:

```
awk -v k="$k" '$0~k&&/something1/&&/something2/{print $2,$3,$4}' *.cfg
```

You mention printing the filename in your question, in this case:

```
awk -v k="$k" '$0~k&&/something1/&&/something2/{print FILENAME;nextfile}' *.cfg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with gnu awk.

```
gawk '/pattern to search/ { print FILENAME; nextfile }' *.files
```

Comment: how do i put this inline in the existing script? it runs separately fine, though slower than grep.